# Trouble with encoding of .265 files. Python script to split them in NAL-units gives UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, encoding

While working on a project, i've hit a dead stop.

Whenever I try to execute the following python script with arguments

```
-i Bitstreams/BasketballDrive.265
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5393d6ec4d2c7f8431e2a97fd750a76d

where the Bitstreams/BasketballDrive.265 is an encoded video file, I get a UnicodeDecodeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mathieu/Documents/Deel-4--Video-3/extractor.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Mathieu/Documents/Deel-4--Video-3/extractor.py", line 79, in main
    extractLayers(args['inputFile'], args['outputFile'], args['temporalLayer'])
  File "C:/Users/Mathieu/Documents/Deel-4--Video-3/extractor.py", line 17, in extractLayers
    gesplit = split_file(voorsplit, "0x00".encode("cp1252"))
  File "C:/Users/Mathieu/Documents/Deel-4--Video-3/extractor.py", line 41, in split_file
    for block in iter(lambda: fp.read(BLOCKSIZE), ''):
  File "C:/Users/Mathieu/Documents/Deel-4--Video-3/extractor.py", line 41, in <lambda>
    for block in iter(lambda: fp.read(BLOCKSIZE), ''):
  File "C:\Users\Mathieu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 192: character maps to <undefined>
```

(Error was produced without specifying the encoding on the `open(INPUTFILENAME)`)

If I include

```
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

I get

```
>>> utf-8
```

Adding `encoding="utf-8` to the `open(INPUTFILENAME)` didn't work either.

Python version : 3.5

Windows version : W8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the files in binary mode;

```
open(INPUTFILENAME, 'rb')
```

By default, Python 3 opens files in text mode. This implies trying to make a `str` out of the contents when reading. This is generally not what you want to do with a binary file.

Comment: Well, that fixed the problem described above. Gonna accept in 10 mins.